# Size restrictions in mat-fileupload-queue

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-file-upload

Is there anyway that i can restrict the size of the file getting uploaded?

I use,

```
  <div>
   <input id="singleFile" type="file" [fileUploadInputFor]="fileUploadQueue" />
   <mat-file-upload-queue #fileUploadQueue [fileAlias]="'file'"
              [httpUrl]="'http://localhost:5000/fileupload'">
    <mat-file-upload [file]="file" [id]="i" *ngFor="let file of fileUploadQueue.files; let i = index">
    </mat-file-upload>
   </mat-file-upload-queue>
 </div>
```

I need like, the error has to be thrown after selecting the file.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it but it is a bit hacky, check out
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-ybmpb7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   stackblitz. You can access the size of the file once it has been selected via `fileUploadQueue.files[n].size`.

I have added a function in the component that checks the first uploaded file for its size and added also a simple expression in the template to show how to access the file size.

It obviously needs some improvement but should get your started.

Comment: great work. but now obsolete, on v3 of fileuploader. any suggestions. also relates to open Issue/featurerequest: https://github.com/nishantmc/angular-material-fileupload/issues/12